# /auth/twitter not found

Tags: servicestack

I am working on implementing Twitter authentication into my ServiceStack implementation.  I am using the [Social Bootstrap API found here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) for reference.

In my apphost I have the following code:

```cs
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] 
    { 
        new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings)
    }));
```

The following options are specified in my `web.config`; `oauth.twitter.ConsumerKey`, `oauth.twitter.ConsumerSecret`, `oauth.twitter.RedirectUrl`, and `oauth.twitter.CallbackUrl`.

I am using the following code in my unit test to test Twitter authentication:

```cs
var authenticate = restClient.Post<AuthService>(
    "/auth/twitter?format=json",
    new Auth()
    {
        UserName = "username",
        Password = "password",
        RememberMe = true
     });
```

`/auth/credentials` works fine for the SQL based authentication I setup (I removed the line registering my custom `AuthProvider` for the sample above).  I receive a 'Not found' error for the `/auth/twitter` endpoint.

Is there something I am missing?  My understanding is that authentication endpoints are available at `/auth/[provider]`.

I am using Service Stack version 3.9.35.0 with an ASP.NET Web forms project in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's relevant but [ServiceStack's SocialBootstrap API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/) is an ASP.NET MVC application with ServiceStack [hosted at /api](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/api/metadata). So if you're getting a **404** try prefixing your route with `/api/`.

The Twitter, Facebook Auth and all the other [Open Id providers in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/OpenId) requires html redirects and manual acceptance so isn't able to be tested like a normal C# integration test.

Basically you would need to use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) that allows you to do a full end-to-end integration test that can simulate a user using a browser.

#### Other notes:

You never want to prefix **?format=json** when using a [C# ServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) as the format is already sent in the **HTTP Accept** header with every request. Also you generally don't need to specify custom routes as services will automatically fallback to using ServiceStack's pre-defined routes if no Custom route exists.

So if you could test twitter authentication with C# clients, you could change:

```
var restClient = new JsonServiceClient(...);
var authenticate = restClient.Post<AuthService>(
"/auth/twitter?format=json",
new Auth()
{
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    RememberMe = true
 });
```

to this more succinct version:

```
var restClient = new JsonServiceClient(...);
var authenticate = restClient.Post(new Auth {
    provider = "twitter",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    RememberMe = true
});
```

Comment: Okay, I tried testing using the web page the service is being created for instead of using a C# unit test.  The webpage is strictly HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS.  I am sending the request via jQuery.ajax.  I tested sending the following request:


http://localhost:6230/auth/twitter?Auth={{provider:twitter,Username:username,UserPassword:password}}

I am redirected to http://localhost:6230/index.html#f=RequestTokenFailed.

Comment: That isn't right, check the online demo at http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com for a working example. Use Fiddler or Chrome Web Inspector to inspect the valid HTTP traffic + requests.

Comment: Okay, I tried /auth/twitter and still received the error, it is not redirecting me to Twitter to authorize the application.  I tried /auth/facebook and it worked great.

I have my Twitter app configured for read access only, does it require a different permissions level?

Comment: For anyone else getting RequestTokenFailed: you need to specify a Callback URL in your Twitter app settings, doesn't matter what it is if you are developing locally, just have to have something.